# PhpSpreadsheet: Is it possible to open and read xlsx-file that protected with password?

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

So I have a xlsx-file protected with password. I want to read data from this file and import to database. But if I want to read password protected file I get:

> "ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object"

Example of my code:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
try {
     $spreadsheet = $reader->load($request->file('report_file'));
     dd($spreadsheet);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
     dd($exception->getMessage());
    }
```

If I am trying to open not protected file that is OK.

Comment: The error appears to be related to a protected ZIP file not a spreadsheet file.

Comment: I've tried the following: save new Excel file with password. Then I've tried to open this new one. Result is the same. Does this mean that Excel file with password automatically becomes the ZIP-file?

Comment: I stand corrected, it isn't related to a ZIP file. Apparently phpSpreadSheet uses the PHP ZipArchive class for several things.According to GitHub the ability to read password protected spreadsheets is still not available.